# Load big file from Google Cloud Storage into Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cloud, google-cloud-storage

Is there a way to load big files (>100MB) from Google Cloud Storage into Google Cloud Functions? I read in their [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas) that the "Max event size for background functions" is limited to 10MB. Can I read it chunk-wise or something like that?

Many thanks.

Comment: Where do the files comes from? If they come from a client-device, use the [Firebase SDK for Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/) to upload the files.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen They are stored in a Google Cloud Storage bucket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud Functions for Storage are triggered with the metadata for the file, which is relatively small and won't hit the max-event-side limit.

To [access the actual contents of the file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events#download_transform_and_upload_a_file), you'll use the node.js package for Cloud Storage, which is not affected by the 10MB limit.

Comment: This is simply false. You cannot download or upload files >10MB from/to Google Cloud Functions. You wont get an error, the function will simply time out.

Comment: If your functions times out, that is related to a combination of file size and on the transfer speed. E.g. it is possible to time out while downloading a 1Mb file from a service that offers a bandwidth of 1Kb/s. Of course larger files have a higher chance of timing out, but the primary cause of failure is the time it takes to download in that case.

Comment: This is from google cloud functions, to google cloud storage. A file of 9MB succeeds in under a second. a file of 11MB times out after 5minutes (300s). Here is a link from someone else that has tried something similar and got the same results with video processing: https://codepen.io/positlabs/post/ffmpeg-in-google-cloud-functions#

Comment: This question was related to a more general concern: the 10Mb event data limit does not automatically imply that there's no way to process files >10Mb. There could well be a limit with specific service combinations and function code, in which case I recommend you open a specific question for that with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (for which the linked codepen *may* be a great start).

Comment: For example: the blog post you linked fails because they're reading the video data from the request, where the 10MB *does* apply. If they'd stream the same data from a service, it would not hit that limit.

Comment: I agree with Frank, the 10MB limit does not apply to files downloaded by the cloud function. I tested this with a firebase https callable function that successfully computed the correct MD5 hash of a 15MB file.

Comment: As an update, I tested a 100MB file which worked fine but failed on a 200MB file. The files tested were all public (I can know for certain that the 15MB file was on AWS).

Comment: @user425678 to clarify, are you saying it's now possible to upload files > 10 MB to google cloud functions?

Comment: @Crashalot No, my comment was only in relation to files downloaded by the function. The size of the request/uploaf has a limit of 10MBs as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @user425678 thanks for the fast reply. what's the best way to bypass this limit if we need to process files > 10 MB? for instance, we use google cloud functions as an API gateway and need to process files > 10 MB in size.

Comment: @Crashalot you could send a link to the cloud function and let it download the file. If you can't host the file (eg the calling code is a smartphone app) then you could upload the file to cloud storage first and then send the link.

Comment: @user425678 thanks for the clarification. so the GCF function could download a file > 10 MB. is it able to send a response > 10 MB? we need to modify the file then send the new file to a user. thanks for your help!

Comment: @Crashalot I don't know what the response limit is but I imagine it's along the 10MB mark, last time I looked it was documented on the website. You'll probably have reply with a download link.

Comment: @user425678 since we need to use GCF as an api gateway, it seems google cloud endpoints will work and don't come with the 10 MB request/response constraints. thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately to my knowledge this isn't possible.

It is however possible to upload larger files from Google Cloud Functions to Cloud Storage by setting resumable=true. The way this works is that it uploads 10MB of the file to your bucket, the request eventually times out and retries, which will then re-download, re-process and re-upload the the file, resuming from where it left of with the next 10MB of the file, and so on.

Obviously this requires all processing to be done repeatedly and the request to time out making the entire process extremely inefficient and not recommended.